# Alternative for Mpm_itk which is working with HTTP2

Tags: php, linux, debian, apache2, http2

I need separate multiple users for every website on my server. I want use mpm_itk but this module is not compatible with http2 module (Apache server). Is some alternative for mpm_itk working with http2 module?

Answer (score 1):

Not really...

We used (and still use) mpm_itk on many (debian) servers, but are switching to:

- proxy_fcgi/php-fpm with separate fpm pool per vHost for PHP handling
- suexec (suexec-custom) for CGI/Perl handling
- mod-qos for request limiting per vHost
- clever or more advanced permission/ownership settings on file-system
- no longer offering SSI

in order to achieve about the same as we do with itk